# How to change "Not Done" to "Done"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. I am having a problem. I can't make Not Done a Done. I would like to beg for help. If not difficult, I would like an example of how to implement this. If I have errors, sorry. I am bad in English.

[image]

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        completed: true
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  render () {
  const { items} = this.props
  return (
    <table>
        {items.map(item => (
            <tr className="hr">
              <td className="col1">{item.id}</td>
              <td className="col2">{item.text}</td>
              <td className="col3">{item.date}</td>
              <td className="col4">{this.state.сompleted ? 'Done' : 'Not Done'}</td>
              <td className="col5"><button onClick ={ this.handleClick }className="btn btn-xs btn-success img-circle">&#x2713;</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
    </table>
  )
  }

    handleClick() {
      console.log('---', 'completed')
    //   this.setState({
    //       completed: !this.state.completed
    // })
    if (this.state.completed = true) {
      this.state.completed = false
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: You must use setState when updating state in django

Comment: Does the commented out code not work?

Comment: It should work .

Comment: It's not specifically the problem but you keep single step for all of your items.. so once you mark one as done, all of items will changed to `done` or `not done` together.

Comment: There is a typo in your if statement. You need a double equal symbol **==** => *if (this.state.completed == true)*

Comment: @MoshFeu Or can an example of this

Comment: @abdurrahmansyzdykov sure. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xzzvzu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your `this.state.completed` because you c in completed is having different font

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        completed: true
    }
  }
  handleClick=()=> {
   this.setState(prevState=>({completed:!prevState.completed}))
  }  
  render () {
  const { items} = this.props
  const { completed } = this.state;
  return (
    <table>
    {items.map(item => (
        <tr className="hr">
          <td className="col1">{item.id}</td>
          <td className="col2">{item.text}</td>
          <td className="col3">{item.date}</td>
          <td className="col4">{completed ? 'Done' : 'Not Done'}</td>
          <td className="col5"><button onClick ={ this.handleClick }className="btn btn-xs btn-success img-circle">&#x2713;</button></td>
        </tr>
      ))}
</table>
  )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign values directly to state attribute. Use `setState()` instead.

Your handler function could be:

```
 handleClick = () => {  // arrow functions are bound by default
      console.log('---', 'completed');
      this.setState({ completed: !this.state.completed });
}
```

Comment: I did but failed

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.state.completed = true) {
      this.setState({completed:false })
    }
```

Comment: I did but failed

Comment: Add comments to your answer, don't post a pure code.

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the state when clicking the button

```
this.setState(prevState => ({completed: !prevState.completed}))
```

Edit:

I think that the problem is not clear here.

The OP have an array of `items` and he wants to set `Done` or `Not Done` only to the clicked item.

The commented code works, but it changes the state for every item, which isn't what the OP wants. To solve this problem, you need to have a property `completed` for every item and update only the property of the item.

Comment: you should have used a double equal (==) sign for your condition

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
You cant change states directly like this:

```
this.sate.completed = !this.state.completed
```

you must use method "this.setState" as follow:

```
this.setState({completed: !this.state.completed})
```

**2)** the "if" sintax is also wrong, you should use double "==", like this:

```
if (this.state.completed == true) {
  ...
}
```

**3)** You should use arrow functions:

```
handleClick = () => {
  ...
```

}

otherwise you need to call your function like:

```
this.handleClick.bind(this)
```